# Runtime database connection using Spring JDBC in Spring boot

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jdbc, runtime

I have a requirement wherein a user enters database connection details through a UI, and then from the application I connect to this database, extract the data, and import into my current application.

Users can enter any database connection information, hence these details are dynamic at a user level. I am using Spring boot and Spring JDBC currently, however I was looking for options to connect to other relational databases dynamically during runtime in order to extract data and import to my application database.

Comment: Fix some run-on sentences.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How to connect to databases while application running and apply connection pool

Comment: Have a look to `DriverManagerDataSource`. You just do `new DriverManagerDataSource(url, user, pword)` and you get a datasource if you have the plugin related to the type of that datasource (oracle, mysql, H2, ...) in the project dependencies.

Comment: Hi, Do I need to use any external connection pooling if I use DriverManagerDataSource or it uses default internal Spring connection Pool